# sed : add something at the end of each line preceding a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I would like to add a semicolon at the end of each line preceding a pattern.
For example, I have the following text :

```
INSERT INTO line 1
INSERT INTO line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
INSERT INTO line 6
```

And I would like to have this :

```
INSERT INTO line 1;
INSERT INTO line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5;
INSERT INTO line 6;
```

I first used the sed command :

```
sed -i '/^INSERT/ s/$/;/'
```

But the problem is that I will have a semicolon at the end of line 2 and not at the end of line 5.
What would be the solution to do this automatically at the end of each line preceding an INSERT INTO in a file with thousands of samples like this one ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: what is your `sed` version? does it have `-z` option? `sed -z 's/\nINSERT/;&/g'` would be simplest logic imo, though not suited if your input file is too large

Comment: It is called semicolon.

Comment: Haha thanks user31264 I corrected it. 
Great @Sundeep it works ! I have version 4.2.2 and it worked with my file of 477 MB, approx. 300k lines.

Comment: I just noticed that there is `;` for last line as well.. is that optional?

Comment: If you don't want to read the whole file in it isn't much harder `sed 'N;s/\nINSERT/;&/;P;D'`

Comment: @Sundeep yes I also would like to add a semicolon at the end of the last INSERT INTO... Is sed -e "\$aTEXTTOEND" the good solution ?
Thank you 123 I will test it.

Answer (score 1):

1 store the text into a file:
`cat data.txt`
result:

```
INSERT INTO line 1
INSERT INTO line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
INSERT INTO line 6
```

2 the awk script content is:
`cat awk.script`
result:

```
{
if (NR==1) {lastline=$0;}
if (NR>1 && $1 == "INSERT") {print lastline";";lastline=$0;} 
if (NR>1 && $1 != "INSERT") {print lastline;lastline=$0;}
}
END{if(lastline ~ /INSERT/) print lastline";";else print lastline; }
```

3 Execute the awk command:
`awk -f awk.script data.txt`
result:

```
INSERT INTO line 1;
INSERT INTO line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5;
INSERT INTO line 6;
```